# How to update height Constraints by SnapKit and update cell height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, snapkit

I have a TableViewCell and two button to switch different constrain.
I want to update it's height constrain and cell height.
like following pic1
when I click buttonB, the view will change like pic2
Then I click buttonA, the view will back to pic1
I try to modify constrains, but I fail to update height.
Have any idea or answer to me?
Thanks

**pic1**

[image]

**pic2**

[image]

Here is code:

```
class CellContainView: UIView {

let buttonA: UIButton = { () -> UIButton in
    let ui = UIButton()
    ui.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    ui.setTitle("Click\nA", for: .normal)
    ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return ui
}()

let buttonB: UIButton = { () -> UIButton in
    let ui = UIButton()
    ui.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    ui.setTitle("Click\nB", for: .normal)
    ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    return ui
}()

let buttonC: UIButton = { () -> UIButton in
    let ui = UIButton()
    ui.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    ui.setTitle("Click\nC", for: .normal)
    ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    return ui
}()

let labelA: UILabel = { () -> UILabel in
    let ui = UILabel()
    ui.text = "Test"
    return ui
}()

let viewA: UIView = { () -> UIView in
    let ui = UIView()
    ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return ui
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addUI()
    addConstrain()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func addUI() {

    self.addSubview(buttonA)
    self.addSubview(buttonB)
    self.addSubview(buttonC)
    self.addSubview(labelA)
    self.addSubview(viewA)

}

func addConstrain() {

    buttonA.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(60)
    }

    buttonB.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(buttonA.snp.right)
        make.top.right.equalToSuperview()
        make.width.equalTo(buttonA.snp.width)
        make.height.equalTo(buttonA.snp.height)
    }

    buttonC.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(15)
        make.right.equalTo(-15)
        make.bottom.equalTo(-15)
        make.height.equalTo(50)
    }

    labelA.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(15)
        make.top.equalTo(buttonA.snp.bottom).offset(15)
        make.width.equalTo(195)
        make.height.equalTo(50)
    }

    viewA.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(labelA.snp.right)
        make.top.equalTo(buttonA.snp.bottom).offset(15)
        make.right.equalTo(-15)
        make.height.equalTo(50)
        make.bottom.equalTo(buttonC.snp.top).offset(-10)
    }
}

func updateConstrain(sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender {
    case buttonA:

        viewA.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalTo(50)
        }

    case buttonB:

        viewA.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalTo(150)
        }

    default:
        break
    }

}

}
```

```
class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let cellContainView: CellContainView = { () -> CellContainView in
    let ui = CellContainView()
    ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    return ui
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.addSubview(cellContainView)

    cellContainView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.top.equalTo(15)
        make.bottom.right.equalTo(-15)
    }

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let tableView: UITableView = { () -> UITableView in
    let ui = UITableView()
    return ui
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    tableView.register(TestTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell")
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
}

@objc func buttonAClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! TestTableViewCell
    cell.cellContainView.updateConstrain(sender: sender)
    tableview.reloadData()
}

@objc func buttonBClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! TestTableViewCell
    cell.cellContainView.updateConstrain(sender: sender)
    tableview.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

    cell.cellContainView.buttonA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.cellContainView.buttonB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonBClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

}
```

**Update constrain problem when I click butttonB (Add update viewA heightConstrain & tableview.reloadData()):**

```
TestCellUpdateHeight[29975:5195310] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a4320@CellContainView.swift#75 UIButton:0x7fa1d0d0d680.height == 60.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a49e0@CellContainView.swift#89 UIButton:0x7fa1d0d10610.height == 50.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a51c0@CellContainView.swift#104 UIView:0x7fa1d0d11130.height == 150.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a4800@CellContainView.swift#80 UIButton:0x7fa1d0d0f7b0.top == TestCellUpdateHeight.CellContainView:0x7fa1d0d0d470.top>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a4a40@CellContainView.swift#82 UIButton:0x7fa1d0d0f7b0.height == UIButton:0x7fa1d0d0d680.height>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a4ec0@CellContainView.swift#88 UIButton:0x7fa1d0d10610.bottom == TestCellUpdateHeight.CellContainView:0x7fa1d0d0d470.bottom - 15.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a5100@CellContainView.swift#102 UIView:0x7fa1d0d11130.top == UIButton:0x7fa1d0d0f7b0.bottom + 15.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a5220@CellContainView.swift#105 UIView:0x7fa1d0d11130.bottom == UIButton:0x7fa1d0d10610.top - 10.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a52e0@TestTableViewCell.swift#26 TestCellUpdateHeight.CellContainView:0x7fa1d0d0d470.top == TestCellUpdateHeight.TestTableViewCell:0x7fa1d208a000.top + 15.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x6040000a53a0@TestTableViewCell.swift#27 TestCellUpdateHeight.CellContainView:0x7fa1d0d0d470.bottom == TestCellUpdateHeight.TestTableViewCell:0x7fa1d208a000.bottom - 15.0>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002819f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' TestCellUpdateHeight.TestTableViewCell:0x7fa1d208a000'TestTableViewCell'.height == 230   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

Answer (score 8):

In general, to update the height constraint of a `uiview:UIView` you should save it first:

```
var viewHeightConstraint: Constraint!
uiview.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    viewHeightConstraint = make.height.equalTo(50).constraint
}
```

If you simply use `updateConstraints` function, it will add a new height constraint that causes the issue `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`. So you have to remove the last one:

```
viewHeightConstraint.deactivate()
```

Then make constraint again:

```
uiview.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    viewHeightConstraint = make.height.equalTo(100).constraint
}
```

Comment: u are setting variable value, not reference -> no need to keep track to viewHeightConstraint

Answer (score 3):

If you need recalculate height cell (without recreate cells / reload cells) just call:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you currently do

```
labelA.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
   make.bottom.equalTo(buttonC.snp.top).offset(-100)
}
```

will increase the bottom distance of the labelA , but will leave it's top constant the same you need to either

1- Update the height of the `labelA`

or

2- Update the height of the redView in front of it

Also don't forget to call

```
cell.cellContainView.updateConstrain(sender: sender)
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

note also because of cell reusing you may find other cell stretched , so you need to keep track of stretched cell indices and apply that inside `cellForRowAt`

You can also do this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
   return expandArr[indexPath.row] ? 300 : 100
}
```

where

```
var expandArr = [Bool]()
```

indicating whether the cell is expanded or not , also if you have a model you may add a bool value to it instead of this separate arr ( it's for illustration )

Comment: Thanks. It's a nice advice. But I try and  I also have the same constrain problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update cell's height just by changing its constraint.

Table can only update the height of its cells as a result of `reloadData()` call, after which it will ask its `delegate` for cell's height (or calculate automatically, if your cells are self-sizing).

So, to get the effect you want you might do something like the following.

In `buttonBClicked` method remember the state you want to get (using some variable maybe).

In table delegate's method `tableView(_:, heightForRowAt:)` return the correct height for the cell.

This is not ideal and serves just as a direction for considering your solution. My main point is that you need to reload table view to change cell's height.

Comment: Thanks. but I call the reloadData() and it shows me constrain problem.

Comment: Do you return updated height in tableView(_:, heightForRowAt:)?

Answer (score 1):

i think you don’t need to change Bottom Constraint.what you required is Apply height Constraint to redView.and change it according to your button Selection.

```
func updateConstrain(sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender {
    case buttonA:

        redView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
            make.heigh.equalTo(10)
        }

    case buttonB:

        redView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
             make.heigh.equalTo(100)
        }

    default:
        break
    }

}
}
```

And don’t forget to reload Specific Row after updating Constraint

```
@objc func buttonAClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! TestTableViewCell
    cell.cellContainView.updateConstrain(sender: sender)
    yourtableview.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)


}

@objc func buttonBClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! TestTableViewCell
    cell.cellContainView.updateConstrain(sender: sender)
 yourtableview.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I use this to update constrain, it seems have constrain problem.